# Angular - calling web api HttpPost with FromBody string - body is always null

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I really thought this is very simple, but I am not able to get this work.

I have a c# web api with the following mthod:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateTaskComment(int id,[FromBody]string comment)
{
     //do something
}
```

From the client, using angular httpClient, this is how I am trying to call the web api method:

```
let reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/UpdateTaskComment?id=${id}`,comment,{headers:reqHeaders})
         .subscribe(...)
         //catch error
```

When the call "arrives" to the server the id is fine, but the comment is always null.

**Notes:**

- The reason I tried to use FromBody for a simple string is because it can be a very long one.
- I know I can wrap the string with a model and it will work, but I wanted to know if there is something I am missing here to do it this way

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, you know how to make this work, but you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end it is a very simple answer:

just use JSON.stringify on the string object

```
let reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
this.http.post(`${BASE_URL}/UpdateTaskComment?id=${id}`,JSON.stringify(comment),{headers:reqHeaders})
         .subscribe(...)
         //catch error
```