# how to post raw json data in angular 7

Tags: json, angular, http-post

i want to post the username from angular to asp.net web api.
my post method from server is :

```
 [Route("CheckUserName")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CheckUsernameExist([FromBody] string username){ //return true or false}
```

and in angular

```
checkUserName(userName: string) {
return this.http.post(
  `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/${CHECK_USER_NAME}`,{userName})
  .pipe(map(res => res['result']['status'] as boolean));}
```

{userName} is data for send to server
but server side receive null
i test also  data :

```
userName,
{username:userName},
'"'+userName+'"',
,...
```

---

```
  checkUserName(userName: string) {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post(
  `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/${CHECK_USER_NAME}`, { userName },{ headers: headers })
  .pipe(map(res => res['result']['status'] as boolean));
```

}

i also test with postman and get data on server side correctly
[image: postman test]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time i found

```
       let reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.post(`${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint}/${CHECK_USER_NAME}`, JSON.stringify(userName), { headers: reqHeaders })
      .pipe(map(res => res['result']['status'] as boolean));
```

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54078776/angular-calling-web-api-httppost-with-frombody-string-body-is-always-null)

Answer (score 0):

Send your data in  this format:

```
{userName:userName}
```

Comment: You can use get method too.Write your api like this             [Route("CheckUserName/{username}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CheckUsernameExist(string username)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have to use Post Method for security reasons.